# How to return callback parameter value from its caller?

Tags: scala

I am using a function from third party code, which looks like this:

```
scala> def willCallback(fun: Function1[Int, Unit]) {
     | doWork()
     | fun(1)
     | }
willCallback: (fun: Int => Unit)Unit
```

In my code, I define a function and would like it to return the callback function parameter, to achieve this:

```
scala> def callbackResult():Int = {
     |   willCallback( (i:Int) => {
     |     // What do I put here 
     |     // to make the return value of callbackResult to be i?
     |   })
     | }
```

What can I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: It "works," it just doesn't do what you want. I presume.

Comment: Under the hood `return` is implemented with a thrown and caught exception. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you. I have further clarified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment it seems that you want `willCallback` to block until the callback has executed. Here's how you can do it with the [`Future`/`Promise` API in Scala 2.10](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html),

```
import scala.concurrent._

// Library code (which you can't modify)
def willCallback(fun: Int => Unit) { fun(1) }

// Your code. You can fulfill a `promise` in your callback
def callbackResult(): Int = {
  val p = promise[Int]
  val f = p.future

  willCallback { i: Int =>
    p.success(i)
  }

  // Block until the promise has been fulfilled (the callback has executed).
  // In this case, the return value is 1
  Await.result(f, duration.Duration.Inf)
}
```

Of course, there is the danger that if the callback never executes, your `callbackResult()` method will hang indefinitely. To avoid this danger, it might be better for `callbackResult()` to return `f: Future[Int]` rather than await its `Int` value, as Régis Jean-Gilles suggests.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not clear what you want or expect, but `return` is both confusing to novices and rarely advisable.

Try to formulate your "callback" as an expression or sequence of expression. Something whose last expression is the value you want to "return."

The thing you need to know is that `return` returns from top-level methods, not functions nor inner methods.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question to further clarify my intention.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
def callbackResult(result:Int) = {
   // code
}

willCallback(callbackResult)
```

Another version would be:

```
willCallback( { result =>
   // code
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve, but here's another shot:

```
def callbackResult():Int = {
  var result = 0
  willCallback( (i:Int) => {
    result = i
    // rest of your code
  })
  result
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that `willCallback` is an asynchronous operation (it runs `fun` in another thread). Will your code wait for `fun` to be called before returning `result`?

Comment: It certainly won't, and you would not want to. You should have a look into scala 2.10 futures (and promises). Basically you could turn `result` into a `Promise[Int]`, and change `callbackResult`'s return type to `Future[Int]`.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles That's a good suggestion. I edited my answer to give the details.